# C# Excel Range assigment from array only populating using 1st array value

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to programmatically generate excel sheets for some data analysis, and I'm trying to convert from using cell[i,j] assignments to using range assignments.

The problem is, when I call the following method with the following values:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
List<string> b = new List<string>() {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"};

Wrapper.WriteListInDirection(sheet, a, 1, 1, Direction.Horizontal);
Wrapper.WriteListInDirection(sheet, b, 7, 7, Direction.Vertical);
```

Then the output in the Excel sheet only uses the 1st value in the array.

The code I have is below.  I have verified the range string that I'm using to select, and the array being passed in.  So for item "a" I get in excel "a", "a", "a", "a" in A1:D1 and for "b" I get "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa" for G7:G10.  However, the arr value being passed in is correct (for case "a" it's arr is array[4,1] with 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' and for "b" it's array[1,4] with 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd').

```
   public static void WriteListInDirection<T>(
        Worksheet edo,
        IEnumerable<T> items,
        int cIndex,
        int rIndex,
        Direction dir)
    {
        int iCount = items.Count();
        int cEnd = dir == Direction.Horizontal ? cIndex + iCount - 1 : cIndex;
        int rEnd = (dir == Direction.Horizontal) ? rIndex : rIndex + iCount - 1;

        T[,] arr = new T[cEnd - cIndex + 1, rEnd - rIndex + 1];

        if (dir == Direction.Horizontal)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
            {
                arr[i, 0] = items.ElementAt(i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
            {
                arr[0, i] = items.ElementAt(i);
            }
        }

        string rStr = string.Format("{0}{1}:{2}{3}",
            ConvertColumnNumToLetter(cIndex),
            rIndex,
            ConvertColumnNumToLetter(cEnd),
            rEnd);

        Range r = edo.Range[rStr];
        r.Value = arr;
    }
```

So where am I messing up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I was using the wrong indexing on the array.

I thought the array to be passed into the Range was [column,row], but instead it's [row,column].  Swapping the ordering of this fixed my issue.